# Syntax Error missing before constant error in C program

Tags: c, windows, sockets, memory

```
#include "MAIN.h"
#define port 444    //port number
//port = 18017;

typedef unsigned _int8 uint8;
typedef unsigned _int16 uint16;
typedef unsigned _int32 uint32;

uint32 measurements[18];


void XcpApp_IpTransmit(uint16, Xcp_StatePtr8, uint16);

void main(void)
{

#ifdef XCP_ENABLE
      /*initialise the XCP Ecu Softwares */

    Xcp_Initialize();

#endif
//initialize before start of the operating system

    while(1)
    {
    Timer1();   
    Timer2();
    Timer3();
    }
}
```

/*ERROR IN THIS LINE*/  void XcpApp_IpTransmit(uint16 port, Xcp_StatePtr8 pBytes, uint16 numBytes) // this function must transmit the specified byte on IP connection identified by port
    {

```
        pBytes = &measurements;     // pBytes points to address of the memory
        numBytes = 8;               //number of bytes at pBytes.

         struct sockaddr_in server;  // creating a socket address structure: structure contains ip address and port number
         WSADATA wsa;
         SOCKET s;
         int len;
        //int bytes_recieved;
        //char send_data[1024],recv_data[1024];

        printf("Initializing Winsock\n");
        if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsa)!=0)
        {
            printf("Failed Error Code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Initialised\n");


        //CREATING a SOCKET

        if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
        {
            printf("Could not Create Socket\n");
            return 0;
        }
        printf("Socket Created\n");

        server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;     
        server.sin_port = htons("port");   
        len = sizeof(server);

        //SENDING a data

        /* bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero),8); 

        if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,
                    sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) 
        {
            perror("Connect");
            exit(1);
        }*/

        while(1)
        {

          //bytes_recieved=recv(s,recv_data,1024,0)

          numBytes=recvfrom(s, pBytes, 8, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&server, &len);
          pBytes[numBytes] = '\0';

          if (strcmp(pBytes , "q") == 0 || strcmp(pBytes , "Q") == 0)
          {
           close(s);
           break;
          }

         /* else
           printf("\nreceived data = %s " , pBytes);*/
         // XcpIp_RxCallback (chunkLen, pChunkData, port); 

          /* 
           printf("\nSEND (q or Q to quit) : ");
           gets(send_data);

          if (strcmp(send_data , "q") != 0 && strcmp(send_data , "Q") != 0)
           send(s,send_data,strlen(send_data), 0); */

          else
          {
              //after the data has ben transmitted
           XcpIp_TxCallback (port, numTxBytes);
           //send(s,send_data,strlen(send_data), 0); 
           closesocket(s);
           WSACleanup();
           break;
          }
        }


}
```

I created a memory of 18*4 bytes, specified the port number and later I am calling a function 
    `void XcpApp_IpTransmit(uint16, Xcp_StatePtr8, uint16);` to transmit a data from the memory to the specified port number. I am performing some tasks in the main function. Later function definition is written for the called function (Created a socket and sending the data through the port number and IP address ) 
I am getting errors like this :

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'constant'
error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before 'constant'
error C2059: syntax error : '<Unknown>'
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

Could anyone help me in fixing this Error (Error is in the body of function void XcpApp_IpTransmit(uint16, Xcp_StatePtr8, uint16)) ???????

Comment: Best way to check what is causing syntax error is to comment part of your program and verify if error is gone. Do it until you find problematic spot. You can do it yourself.

Comment: Can u post the code in MAIN.h?

Comment: Post MAIN.h, maybe help

Comment: #pragma once
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")
typedef unsigned _int16 uint16;
typedef unsigned _int32 uint32;
typedef _int32 int32;
typedef unsigned _int8 uint8;
typedef unsigned long  uint32;
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "xcp.h"
#include "LocatedVars.h"
#include <time.h>
#include "Task2ms.h"
#include "Task10ms.h"
#include "Task100ms.h"
#include "TIMER1.h" #include "TIMER2.h" #include "TIMER3.h"
#include "xcp_pub.h" #include "xcpip_pub.h" #include "stopwatch.h"
#include "xcp_common.h" #include "xcp_auto_conf.h"#include "xcp_auto_confpriv.h"

Comment: It contains some header files and some #ifndef TASK2ms_H_
#define TASK2ms_H_
int Timer1();
#endif 




#ifndef TASK10ms_H_
#define TASK10ms_H_
int Timer2();
#endif 



#ifndef TASK100ms_H_
#define TASK100ms_H_
int Timer3();
#endif

Comment: What I feel is, there might be a syntax error in the declaration of Xcp_StatePtr8

Comment: by the way what is Xcp_StatePtr8, how it looks?

Comment: @Nishanth : There is no syntax error. Its just an pointer of type to an variable pBytes.

Comment: Please add relevant information to the question itself, but squeezing it into comments, its hardly readable. Thank you.

Comment: Why do people always do `typedef unsigned _int32 uint32;` instead of `#include <stdint.h>` and using `uint32_t`?

Answer (score 0):

if this is a `C` program, the first error I can see is that your variable declarations in the function `XcpApp_IpTransmit()` are not the first lines of their scope.

in other words, try changing the first few lines of that function to the following:

```
void XcpApp_IpTransmit(uint16 port, Xcp_StatePtr8 pBytes, uint16 numBytes) // this function must transmit the specified byte on IP connection identified by port
{
     struct sockaddr_in server;  // creating a socket address structure: structure contains ip address and port number
     WSADATA wsa;
     SOCKET s;
     int len;
     //int bytes_recieved;
     //char send_data[1024],recv_data[1024];

     pBytes = &measurements;     // pBytes points to address of the memory
     numBytes = 8;               //number of bytes at pBytes.

     printf("Initializing Winsock\n");
     ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I tried that and getting the same errors.

Comment: @user2984410 VS should give you the exact line number where it is detecting the syntax error.  Please find that line and indicate it to us.

Comment: I have updated my code and mention that : /*ERROR IN THIS LINE*/

Comment: @user2984410 I know you mentioned that there is no syntax error in the definition of `Xcp_StatePtr8`, but can you also paste its definition in your question?

Comment: Xcp_StatePtr Pbytes; an instance of this type points to Pbytes of memory in the address. In my case : Pbytes pointing to the address of the meamory (pbytes = &measurements ;)

Comment: @All : Thank you very much . I solved it. I was define the port number in the beginning and passing that as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the line

```
#define port 444    //port number
```

the declaration

```
void XcpApp_IpTransmit(uint16 port, Xcp_StatePtr8 pBytes, uint16 numBytes)
```

is turned into

```
void XcpApp_IpTransmit(uint16 444, Xcp_StatePtr8 pBytes, uint16 numBytes)
```

by the preprocessor. The `444` is the `'constant'` the compiler is complaining about.